# Display data blocks from draftjs

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

How I can display in my **react component**, raw that I was save to mongodb, from **draftjs editor**?

This is what I have in my database:

```
"blocks" : [ 
            {
                "key" : "7abte",
                "text" : "example",
                "type" : "unstyled",
                "depth" : 0,
                "inlineStyleRanges" : [ 
                    {
                        "offset" : 0,
                        "length" : 20,
                        "style" : "BOLD"
                    }
                ],
                "entityRanges" : []
            }
        ]
```

I found out how to return this to Editor (to edit data), everything works great. But I can't display it on front site.

I also tried export my editor content to semantic HTML and this is what I received:
[image: draftjs escape html fail]

but like You see, I don't know how to display it, not as a string but as html..

Do you have any good solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to process the HTML to show in front-end, you should use something like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: YourMarkupVar}} />
```

Else, React as a security measure, will encode the tags and display as normal text.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It works but if it is right and proper way to work with draftjs/react?

Comment: Definitely yes! Think that DraftJS isn't a HTML editor like TinyMCE - you can customize DraftJS to edit only comments, support quotes or whatever you want!